# ajax / php form and variable assignment

Tags: php, ajax

My goal is to submit a set of variables to my AJAX function from with in a while loop in php.  This is my first shot at using AJAX, so please excuse if it is messy, and not close to correct. I appreciate any assistance.

PHP FORM:

```
                x=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $id = $row['col1'];
            $ad = $row['col2'];
            cho '<form id="msu_form">';
            echo "<tr><td>{$ad}</td>";
            echo "<td>";

            $query2 = "SELECT col1,col2 FROM table WHERE notes = 'x'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            $count2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
             if($count2 > 0)
            {
                echo '<select class="Primary" name="primary" onchange=doAjaxPost()>';
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$row2['col1'].">".$row2['col2']."</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
            }else
            {
                echo "Blah";
            }
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";                    
            $query3 = "SELECT col1,col2 FROM table2 WHERE notes = 'y'";
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
            $count3 = mysql_num_rows($result3);
            if($count3 > 0)
            {
                 echo '<select class="Secondary" name="secondary">';
                 while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$row3['col1'].">".$row3['col2']."</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
            }else
            {
                echo "Bah";
            }
            echo "</td>";
            echo '<input type="hidden" class="ID" name="ID" value="'.$id.'"/>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" class="desc" name="desc" value="'.$ad.'"/>';
            //echo '<td>'."<input type='submit' name='btnupdate' value='UPDATE' /></td>";
            echo '</form>';
            $x = $x+1;
         }
```

So what happens is every time I change any of the "primary" select boxes on the screen, I get the value of the variables on the first line only.  I want to receive the values of the form from the select box.  I have tested it via a button, that submits the form it is commented out, but that button submits all the correct information to the page, but I don't want to submit the data every time.  Is there a way to accomplish my goal?

Thanks - below the ajax if it helps with an answer.

```
                    <script>  
                function doAjaxPost() {  
                 // get the form values  
                 var primary = $(this).val();
                 var secondary = $(this).parent().next().child('.Secondary').val();
                 var hidden = $(this).parent().nextAll('.ID').val();
                 //var desc = $(this).parent().nextAll('#desc').val();
                 $.ajax({  
                   type: "POST",  
                   url: "functions/database_write.php",
                   data: $('#msu_form').serialize(),
                   //data: "Primary="+primary+"&Hidden="+hidden+"&Secondary="+secondary,
                   success: function(resp){  
                      //we have the response  
                    alert("'" + resp + "'");  
                   },  
                   error: function(e){  
                     alert('Error: ' + e);  
                   }  
                 });  
                }  
                </script>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: How many times does `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))` loop? If more than 1 time, you will have `n` number of `id=Primary`, `n` number of `id=Secondary`, `n` number of `id="ID"`, and `n` number of `id="desc"`. Since `id`s are supposed to be unique in a document, your jQuery is finding the 1st of each `id`, not the always the one you want.

Comment: It loops many times, if I have a variable that is always changing, how do I reference it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your php code change the following 4 lines (using `id`)

```
echo "<select id=Primary name=primary onchange=doAjaxPost()>"; 
echo "<select id=Secondary name=secondary>";
echo '<input type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" value="'.$id.'"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="desc" name="desc" value="'.$ad.'"/>';
```

to (using `class`) **edited**

```
echo '<select class="Primary" name="primary" onchange="doAjaxPost(this)">'; //added (this)
echo '<select class="Secondary" name="secondary">';
echo '<input type="hidden" class="ID" name="ID" value="'.$id.'"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" class="desc" name="desc" value="'.$ad.'"/>';
```

Then, in your javascript code, change

```
function doAjaxPost() {
 var primary = $('#Primary').val();  
 var secondary = $('#Secondary').val();
 var hidden = $('#ID').val();
 var desc = $('#desc').val();
```

to **edited**

```
function doAjaxPost(sel) { // added (sel)
 var primary = $(sel).val();  //changed to $(sel)
 var secondary = $(sel).parent().next().children('.Secondary').val(); //changed to $(sel) and changed to children()
 var hidden = $(sel).parent().nextAll('.ID').val(); //changed to $(sel) and changed to nextAll()
 var desc = $(sel).parent().nextAll('#desc').val(); //changed to $(sel) and changed to nextAll()
```

Comment: I changed as you recommended, and now nothing at all happens?  As if the script is not running?

Comment: Sorry, my example was untested, so there were some errors. I have edited my answer. In you php need to have `onchange="doAjaxPost(this)"`, where the `this` is to reference which select was changed. Then in your js -> `function doAjaxPost(sel) { ... $(sel)...` where `sel` references your select. Please see the edited code sections.

Comment: thank you, but it is still not working?  It appears the script is not running? Anything I could be missing?  Thanks again.

Comment: Using the 2 edited code blocks I have in my answer should work. Here is a jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/nTA96/

Answer (score 0):

If everything works fine when submitting normally, then probably you are generating the ajax data wrong, instead give your form an id:

```
echo '<form id="myform">';
```

Then serialize the form to get the correct data:

```
function doAjaxPost() {  

 $.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   url: "functions/data.php",  
   data: $('#myform').serialize(),
   success: function(resp){  
      //we have the response  
    alert("'" + resp + "'");  
   },  
   error: function(e){  
     alert('Error: ' + e);  
   }  
 });  
}
```

EDIT Ok you edit has cleared things up a bit, I didn't notice you have multiple forms.

Using the same doAjaxPost function as above,  change the data property to:

```
  data: $(this).parents('form').serialize();
```

Comment: I tried what you advised, but now instead of the first line always being returned, the second line is only being submitted. And there are many more than two lines.

Comment: @user3582887 please edit your question to show the generated html as the php is hard to follow

Comment: Ok, I edited my question after I attempted to rename the ID's with a variable that continuously changes, I am returning - print_r($_POST) and I am still getting one line all the time.  The index is only for that one line (for example x is equalling 1) so I get back primary1 => 1000, secondary1 => 450, ID1 = 903... so eventhough there is a unique name to each index, still not choosing the correct line?

Comment: I have modified my code to the suggested data property, it runs the function, but now returns an empty array?  Thanks for all the input thus far.